# Java Technologies

Tags: java, web, client-server

I am designing an IT healthcare system for academic purposes. I would like to create a database in an ordinary Internet web-domain and a separate Java client-application.

Somehow I want the client to have access in the database through Internet. I am looking for the technology to implement that. I would really appreciate if you could share any ideas of how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving direct access to the database over the public Internet is a discredited approach. Instead applications are designed as *three-tiered*, such that on the server side you have a dedicated application server which communicates with the database as needed.

There are many frameworks which make this task easier, such as Grails (lightweight), the Spring Framework (industrial-strength, quite heavyweight), or the Java EE platform (more heavyweight than Spring).

Comment: Just curious, but why is Java EE more heavyweight than Spring?

Comment: Because Spring is a set of mix-and-match components whereas the JEE container is a monolith.

Comment: Typical Java EE containers load on demand what the application needs. If your application doesn't use say JMS or JCA, it's not loaded and doesn't use any resources. Again just wondering, but do you also mix-and-match your OS together, or do you just install Windows, OS X, Ubuntu, etc?

Comment: @ArjanTijms The point is, you don't have much *choice* once you have picked your EE container. Spring will mingle much better with other techs because its central paradigm is just the lightweight IoC container, to which anything can contribute via well-specified interfaces (whose counterparts in EE are relegated to "implementation detail" which you have no control over). Spring is also very open to extension and practically any internal part can be customized. Also, clearly the JEE platform has been evolving towards Spring's concepts over time.

Comment: Actually, there is quite a lot of choice in Java EE. There is an official extension mechanism that centers around Java EE's ultra-lightweight IoC container called CDI, that is not only type-safe, but build around no-XML principles. It's been inspired by Seam and Guice. Other parts are build for extension too. There has been an official connector plug-in system like forever (JCA) and the UI framework is fully focussed on extension points and has a well documented component model, so third party libraries can deliver extensions and component sets.

Comment: >`whose counterparts in EE are relegated to "implementation detail" which you have no control over` - Which things are exclusively relegated to being an implementation detail then?

Comment: Take Spring AOP: it's a well-defined publicly exposed infrastructure which supports things like error handling, transactions, security, and much more. Spring eat their own dogfood and implement transaction management exclusively relying on the public API of AOP while giving their customer the chance to do anything they need on their own. Plus, the entire Transaction Manager is an example of a highly modularized, pluggable, and customizable subsystem. If there is an equivalent of that in *some* JEE container, there certainly isn't in the JEE public API.

Comment: `There is an official extension mechanism that centers around [...] CDI`---that just reinforces my point: JEE is full of individual, *special-cased* extension mechanisms. Granted, CDI is the most versatile among them, but it's still an extension mechanism. Spring is based *from the ground up* on the IoC container---*everything* is a named bean in it, and everything gets enrolled to it by the same unified, user-controlled mechanism. You have the choice of manually setting up every last bean, or using predefined, customizabe templates to set up complete subsystems with a single directive.

Comment: `It's been inspired by Seam and Guice`---if you mean to imply that CDI *wasn't* inspired by Spring, I can just reiterate the obvious fact that Spring introduced the concept of a lightweight IoC container as the foundation of enterprise application architecture back in 2002---and did so precisely in *opposition* to the J2EE architecture. The details of CDI's design may have influences from the projects you name, but the very *idea* of CDI comes from Spring.

Comment: `CDI, that is not only type-safe, but build around no-XML principles.`---Spring has had typesafe XML-less dependency injection since version 2.5 (released in 2007).

Comment: >`Spring has had typesafe XML-less dependency injection since version 2.5` - And Java EE since EJB 3.0 (2006). Spring didn't fully embrace no-XML until much later, way after CDI was introduced. As I remember, Spring was still preaching to move more code into XML (calling it 'config', but we all know it was just code), long after the Java industry as a whole started to move away from XML. At no point was Spring leading the no-XML and type-safe injection movements.

Comment: 'Spring introduced the concept of a lightweight IoC container as the foundation of enterprise application architecture back in 2002' - AFAIK, Spring 1.0 was released in March 2004, and it didn't invent IoC nor did it invent injection. JSF 1.0 happened to be released at the exact same time, and it featured a rather lightweight IoC/DI container as well.

Comment: Some of us have been using Spring *before* version 1.0. `it didn't invent IoC nor did it invent injection`---now you seem to be putting words into my mouth. No, Spring didn't invent those, but that's beside the point in any case. To quote myself, Spring's contribution was the application of IoC `as the foundation of enterprise application architecture`.

Comment: >`the very idea of CDI comes from Spring` I don't think this is fully accurate. CDI strongly focussed on *contextual* injections (the C that CDI adds to DI), which was directly inspired by JSF's managed beans. While there undoubtedly have been influences, it's absolutely not as strong as you seem to think. Gavin King, the driving force and initial spec lead behind CDI, has stated that Guice and Seam were his inspiration. See http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/WebBeansSneakPeekPartIIntroducingWebBeans

Comment: >`as the foundation of enterprise application architecture` - In my humble opinion this is not very concrete. I worked with a C++ system in 1995/1996 that used IoC/DI intensively (everything was centered around it, we called it "smart classes" in that project) and it was an enterprise application (but what exactly constitutes an "enterprise application" is not entirely well defined).

Comment: >`the entire Transaction Manager is an example of a highly modularized, pluggable, and customizable subsystem` - Yet, it doesn't actually implement any actual transaction managing itself, but in practice strongly relies on Java EE implementations of Java EE specs such as JTA and JTS.

Comment: `it doesn't actually implement any actual transaction managing itself`---it implements transaction management of raw JDBC connections obtained from `DataSource`s and raw `JMS` connection factories. *In addition to that* it interoperates with JEE-standard transaction APIs (among several others)---all in the good tradition of Spring to be inclusive, not exclusive. FWIW I have yet to write a Spring-based application which would use the `JtaTransactionManager`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest developing locally.

Run your database on Vagrant or just a plain old VM and treat it like its an external database server.